How to integrate private app in Go High Level sub account
In Go High Level marketplace, I have a private app which is a custom payment provider.
I want to integrate that into another subaccount. For public apps, we can get the app from the marketplace and install it.
Since, the app is private. How can that be integrated and installed into the subaccount.

Private App: A private app is restricted to a specific group or individuals. It is not publicly listed in the Marketplace and requires an invitation or authorization to access and use.

This is mentioned in Go High Level documentation but I can't find any further information on how to send invitation or authorization.

you should try one api call for authorization with private app cliendId and other necessary params and app will apear in your ghl dashboard. After you select on ghl widget sub or agency account it will be installed.
